# Windows not booting up from usb

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, boot

I have HP laptop which I disassembled and after assembling tried to start it which had windows 10. But it didn't start out. Only loading symbol.

After which I tried reinstalling Windows but again faced same issue.

Later on I tried to install Ubuntu, this time it installed successfully.

Again I tried windows but not worked. I want Windows and stuck with the issue.

Comment: Windows needs to have the USB driver, etc. loaded before it really attempts to boot.  Linux solves this with an initial ram disk (`initrd`) that contains the kernel and any boot critical drivers.  Think you can do similar with Windows, or at least you could forever ago when inserting a SCSI driver disk during the install process.  Not sure how Win10 handles this now, or if it does at all.

Comment: The comment above goes in one way that really doesn't help (but it's technically correct). The problem here is with the Windows dongle you're using. Prefer the official Media creation tool, the default when downloading the Windows ISO from Microsoft.

Comment: I created bootable usb using rufus software, however it works and boots in other PCs but does not works in mine. Should i steel try with official tool.

Comment: @gouravpawar Yes,  Rufus with the wrong settings IS the problem.

Comment: Is the BIOS/firmware of the laptop configured for Legacy or UEFI? Rufus can generate a bootable flash drive for either, but it should match.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I tried with the official windows usb tool. But it did not worked.

Comment: @K7AAY the Bios of the laptop have legacy support enabled and From rufus I used UEFI or CSM as setting.

Comment: Can it be the problem with some configuration file related with windows. As I can login using Ubuntu, is there any way by which I can do something with the C drive, may be clean it kind of.

Comment: @gourav pawar Legacy and UEFI don't mix. UEFI LiveUSBs need legacy mode disabled. Why is legacy mode enabled?

Comment: @K7AAY I used to boot with legacy mode enabled before. Still I tried with both the settings. But no work.  I tried booting usb from 1.rufus 2. Windows media creation tool. 3.windows 7 usb tool. But didn't succeed.